# passing counting argument into a recursive python function

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I successfully solved an algorithm question to serialize and deserialize binary tree.

```
class Codec:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i=0
    def serialize(self, root):
        store=[]
        def preorder(node):
            if not node:
                store.append("N")
                return
            store.append(str(node.val))
            preorder(node.left)
            preorder(node.right)
        preorder(root)
        return ",".join(store)

    # serialized data is passed here as "data" argument             
    def deserialize(self, data):
        values=data.split(",")
        def helper():
            if values[self.i]=="N":
                self.i+=1
                return
            root=TreeNode(int(values[self.i]))
            self.i+=1
            root.left=helper()
            root.right=helper()
            return root
        return helper()
```

to solve the `deserialize` function, I created a top-level state variable `self.i`. Instead, I want to pass `i` to the `helper` function but I cannot figure it out. I tried to code like this with local variable:

```
    def deserialize(self, data):
        values=data.split(",")
        def helper(i):
            if values[i]=="N":       
                i+=1
                return
            root=TreeNode(int(values[i]))    
            i+=1
            root.left=helper(i)
            # i think issue is here.
            # Because i is modified inside root.left=helper(i)
            # so somehow I need to keep track of this modification
            root.right=helper(i)
            return root
        return helper(0)
```

Comment: `i` is a number. Numbers are copied in Python, not passed by reference, so a call with `helper(i)` cannot modify the value of `i` inside the calling function.

Comment: I think the problem you're coming up against is that you're trying to take a recursive approach to a problem which is better solved by other methods - indeed, better solved by the first approach you took. It may even be that you _cannot_ use a purely recursive approach here. You seem need some global state, not state which depends on where in the recursive call tree you're in, so why not embrace it?

Comment: @user19642323 it looks ugly :) also creating local variables are more memory efficient.

Comment: It's Python, nothing about it is efficient ;) On a serious note, I'm not sure it is possible to write a recursive version of your `helper` function that doesn't use some sort of global state.

Comment: I am asynchronously seeking help. till I find a solution, I will stick to my solution

Comment: I need to take an amazon assessment this weekend.  I need to deep dive into everything into algorithms to analyze better

Comment: let me know when you find out that it can't be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an instance attribute (`i`), you could use a local variable `i` like you tried, but then *not* passing it as argument to `helper`, but referencing it as a `nonlocal` name. But I would not advise that. Instead create an iterator over the given values. Then you can call `next` on it to get the next value.

Once you got rid of the ugly instance attribute, you no longer need instances at all, and I wonder why you would need a class `Codec` at all. It you really want to keep it, then create those two functions as *static* methods as it doesn't make sense to ever need to create an instance of `Codec`:

Here is complete code with a run on a sample tree:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = self.right = None

    def add(self, val):
        if val < self.val:
            if self.left:
                self.left.add(val)
            else:
                self.left = TreeNode(val)
        else:
            if self.right:
                self.right.add(val)
            else:
                self.right = TreeNode(val)

    def print(self, tab=""):
        if self.right:
            self.right.print(tab +  "  ")
        print(tab, self.val)
        if self.left:
            self.left.print(tab +  "  ")

    @staticmethod
    def of(*values):
        if values:
            root = TreeNode(values[0])
            for val in values[1:]:
                root.add(val)
            return root

class Codec:
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(root):
        store=[]
        def preorder(node):
            if not node:
                store.append("N")
                return
            store.append(str(node.val))
            preorder(node.left)
            preorder(node.right)
        preorder(root)
        return ",".join(store)
    
    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(data):
        values = iter(data.split(","))
        
        def helper():
            val = next(values)
            if val=="N":
                return
            root = TreeNode(int(val))
            root.left = helper()
            root.right = helper()
            return root
        return helper()

tree = TreeNode.of(4,2,6,1,3,5,7)
tree.print()
s = Codec.serialize(tree)
print(s)
root = Codec.deserialize(s)
root.print()
```